# Specifying sets where/with/for

Tags: word-choice

My main interest is in the mathematical context, where one denotes a set of objects with indices. I can imagine 3 cases :

1. Let *xₙ* for *n*=1,2,... denote all objects ...
2. Let *xₙ* with *n*=1,2,... denote all objects ...
3. Let *xₙ* where *n*=1,2,... denote all objects ...

I would tend to use 2 but I was told this sounds strange.

Comment: Avoid prepositions and other meaningless words in mathematics as far as possible. That's what formal notation is for. *Let **xᵢ** (i ∊ {1,2,3,...}) denote all objects ...*

Comment: @John Lawler Great idea. Using google I see also  _Let_ _xᵢ_, _i_ ∊ {1,2,3,...} _denote all objects_ ... I think I'll go with this.

Comment: A best practice is to apply Math conventions instead of English grammar.

Comment: Let xᵢ (i = 1,2,3 ...) denote all objects. Set notation is unusual.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "with" is not a likely choice, but in fact it is possibly used more often than "where", and "for" is chosen most often: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&smoothing=3&corpus=15&year_end=2008&content=where+n%3D1%2Cfor+n%3D1%2Cwith+n%3D1&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhere%20n%20%3D%201%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20n%20%3D%201%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20n%20%3D%201%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwhere%20n%20%3D%201%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20n%20%3D%201%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20n%20%3D%201%3B%2Cc0).

In this ngram are included all cases in which *n* is fixed and equal to 1, but I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this tool, so your answer was helpful. However, it's not possible to use indices, so I cannot check for the whole phrase. This would be required to sufficiently constrain the context.

Comment: I agree that "for" sounds most natural.  I"d also consider beginning the sentence with "For" and perhaps replacing the equation with words: For natural numbers n, let ....